# Clipping interpolation layer to a coastal boundary in QGIS 3.6?

Tags: qgis-3, clip, interpolation

I have created an interpolation layer and want to clip it so I don't see the area outside the coastal boundary. map showing area to be clipped:

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? A quick google search for "qgis clip raster" shows that there are many resources that already answer this question.